# Extract timestamp data with jumps in MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to get information out of my MySQL database, but the data is stored every 10 seconds and I want to extract it every minute or every hour. I am using this sql command to get the data from a sensor with tagid = 1186. Thanks!.

`SELECT t_stamp, floatvalue FROM database1.sqlt_data_1_2022_01 where tagid=1186;`

console:

```
t_stamp         floatvalue
1641013208360   86.2012939453125
1641013218361   86.32317352294922
1641013228362   86.3144760131836
1641013238365   86.53619384765625
1641013248366   86.37206268310547
1641013258367   86.31449890136719
1641013268368   86.36858367919922
1641013278369   86.26002502441406
1641013288370   86.34619903564453
1641013298375   86.14665985107422
1641013308372   86.06439971923828
1641013318373   86.54731750488281
```

Comment: Please take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me you're asking how to perform a timely job. You can create a record table and store the output from your query every 1 minute or so. Try using 'EVENT'.

```
set @@global.event_scheduler=on; -- first of all enable the event scheduler
delimiter //
CREATE EVENT get_data_every_minute
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 minute STARTS now() DO
BEGIN
insert into record_table SELECT t_stamp, floatvalue FROM database1.sqlt_data_1_2022_01 where tagid=1186;
END//   
delimiter ;
```

On the other hand ,if you intend to read the onscreen output other than storing the data. I would suggest using a procedure to run the query on a timely basis in an infinite loop.

```
delimiter //
create procedure show_result()
begin
while true do
SELECT t_stamp, floatvalue FROM database1.sqlt_data_1_2022_01 where tagid=1186;
select sleep(60); -- in seconds
end while;
end//

delimiter ;
call show_result; -- start the procedure
```

To terminate the procedure(infinite loop) , check the processlist and kill its pid.

```
show processlist; -- the process of the infinite loop looks like below:

| 144306 | root            | %                 | testdb | Query   |    0 | User sleep                  | select sleep(10) |

kill 144306 ; -- kill the pid to stop it
```